# confidence interval with logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval

I have data which consist of 0,1,-1 values somethink like this.

```
    x:{1,1,1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ......}
    y:{1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1 ......}
```

I need to confirm that `data`(x and y) match with formula.I mean those data generate a formula same as or almost same as the below formula.
How can I achive that.

Formula:

```
y = -0,398ln(x) + 1,2694
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. To start with, correlation is an relationship between two vectors or two variables, not between a vector and a function. Perhaps you're misusing the terms "correlation" and "confidence interval".

Comment: I am sorry ,seems u are right.wait..

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what it means for a vector to have a relation with a formula with 90% confidence, either.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to assess the goodness of fit of your model. Where did it come from? If the outcome is 0/1, we usually use logistic regression. Your formula clearly isn't LR. It strikes me as almost certainly inappropriate, but I'm not sure how to check it since I don't know what it is or where it came from. Your x-variable has 3 peculiar levels, is it a continuous variable, an ordinal one, or a categorical variable?

Comment: @gung may be it is my stupidness as I am not statistician.I am getting data when drawing number on surface.at the beginning, data was the surface coordinate of the number(pixel based).Later I applyed filter that when x axis increase ,I represent the 1 ,no changes 0 and decrease -1.after that I implemet LR and get this formula :).thinking each number should have and equation representation.if u have any good idea,let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to quantify how well the formula describes the data is with root mean squared error (RMSE). For each $i$, compute $(-0.398 \ln x_i + 1.2694 - y_i)^2$, then take the square root of the mean of these all these squares. The smaller the RMSE, the better the formula describes the data.